# Incorrect use of NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I was following an example in my book for an `AddressCard` class. One of the methods for the class was a setter `-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName;` I ended up setting up the name for one of my objects like this: `myCard.name = @"Jen";` Then I saw in my book that I was suppose to create an `NSString` object, assign it a string, and use that for the setter. Was what I did incorrect or bad practice?

Comment: If that's the only place where you use @"Jen" to set a value I dont see an issue. It may be beneficial to use a seperate string for the sake of clarity, for example NSString *userName = @"Jen"; myCard.name = userName;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
myCard.name = @"Jen"
```

is setting the string "Jen" to a property named name (i'm guessing of type NSString) that has already been allocated. This is fine.

It is more wise, however, to use the implicit method [myCard setName:@"Jen"]; because it is safer.

Comment: When is it better to use the implicit method over the dot operator?

Comment: it is better to use the implicit method when you are accessing another class and it is better to use dot notation when you are in the same class as the property

Answer (score 1):

```
@"Jen"
```

is a constant NSString -- you can use it as any normal NSString. Nothing is wrong with your code.